# What's the meaning of parameter Priority_boost

Tags: linux, audit

I have searched the web for answers to this. In auditd configuration file auditd.conf there is a parameter priority_boost. The RedHat [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/auditd.conf) says:

```
priority_boost
This is a non-negative number that tells the audit daemon how much of a priority boost it should take. The default is 4. No change is 0.
```

I have difficulty understanding what impact the value has. Can someone shed some light on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through `auditd`'s [source](https://github.com/linux-audit/audit-userspace/blob/v2.8.5/src/auditd.c#L723), `priority_boost` is used to modify `auditd` process [`nice`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/nice) value. The larger this value is, the higher priority of auditd is.

Here's the snippet of auditd's source:

> ```
> ...
>
> if (config.priority_boost != 0) {
> errno = 0;
> rc = nice((int)-config.priority_boost);
> if (rc == -1 && errno) {
>     audit_msg(LOG_ERR, "Cannot change priority (%s)", 
>         strerror(errno));
>     free_config(&config);
>     return 1;
> }
>
> ...
> ```

And the snippet from `nice(1)` man page:

> `nice()` adds inc to the nice value for the calling process. (A higher
>   nice value means a low priority.) Only the superuser may specify a
>   negative increment, or priority increase.

Please note that in the `auditd` snippet, nice is set to `(int)-config.priority_boost`, so that means if you set `priority_boost` to 4, you effectively set its nice to -4, hence higher priority.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!